# how to get tags from user in form and save it to database in django

Tags: django, tags, django-taggit

I have a form that gets some fields and tags from users and save the user input data in database:
By the way I am using taggit

this is my model:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique_for_date='created', allow_unicode=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("questions:question_detail", args=[self.created.year, self.created.month, self.created.day, self.slug])
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and here is my view:

```
def question_form(request):

    new_question = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_form = QuestionForm(data=request.POST)
        if question_form.is_valid():
            new_question = question_form.save(commit=False)
            new_question.slug = slugify(new_question.title)
            new_question.save()
            question_form.save_m2m()
    else:
        question_form = QuestionForm()
    
    return render(request, 
                'questions/que/form.html',
                {'question_form':question_form, 'new_question':new_question})
```

and my form.py is like this:

```
from taggit.forms import TagField



class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'body',)
    tags = TagField()
```

my problem is when user enters the tags and other fields everything is saved in database except the tags! Can anyone help me?